# Laravel 4 ubuntu composer install/update error

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Cloned a laravel application into my ec2 instance and when i run composer update/install i get a [RuntimeException.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUVTD.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check your rights on the folder where you want to install Laravel. It seems that Composer has not right to create a new directory (vendor)